# Split 2D Array into multiple connected pieces by given rows and columns

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, google-apps-script, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to find the most efficient way of breaking a two-dimensional array into different two-dimensional pieces, all stored into a new array which will be returned as the result.

I have a 2D array consisting of a string "N M" in the cell at row N and column M. For example, the value in row 2, column 3 would be "2 3".

Now given some rows and column indexes, I want to remove those rows and columns, and group each "piece" into its own 2D array. A "piece" is a set of orthogonally connected cells, without any intervening cells from the rows and columns removed above.

e.g. if I have an array with 8 rows and 7 columns, and I try to remove the rows `[2, 3, 5]`, and columns `[2, 6]`, the resulting array of "pieces" should be

```
[
  [["0, 0", "0, 1"], ["1, 0", "1, 1"]],
  [["0, 3", "0, 4", "0, 5"], ["1, 3", "1, 4", "1, 5"]],
  [["4, 0", "4, 1"]],
  [["4, 3", "4, 4", "4, 5"]],
  [["6, 0", "6, 1"], ["7, 0", "7, 1"]],
  [["6, 3", "6, 4", "6, 5"], ["7, 3", "7, 4", "7, 5"]]
]
```

In case the description is unclear, I went ahead and made a visual example of the process in mind [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IL4oo.png) to detail the steps, problems and goals involved.

[image: 1]

This is what I was able to come up with, but it's producing arrays that include exception columns. I know why, but I don't know how to get around it short of adding extra complexity which is not conducive to efficiency.

```
const SourceArray = [ ['R0·C0', 'R0·C1', 'R0·C2', 'R0·C3', 'R0·C4', 'R0·C5', 'R0·C6'],
                      ['R1·C0', 'R1·C1', 'R1·C2', 'R1·C3', 'R1·C4', 'R1·C5', 'R1·C6'],
                      ['R2·C0', 'R2·C1', 'R2·C2', 'R2·C3', 'R2·C4', 'R2·C5', 'R2·C6'],
                      ['R3·C0', 'R3·C1', 'R3·C2', 'R3·C3', 'R3·C4', 'R3·C5', 'R3·C6'],
                      ['R4·C0', 'R4·C1', 'R4·C2', 'R4·C3', 'R4·C4', 'R4·C5', 'R4·C6'],
                      ['R5·C0', 'R5·C1', 'R5·C2', 'R5·C3', 'R5·C4', 'R5·C5', 'R5·C6'],
                      ['R6·C0', 'R6·C1', 'R6·C2', 'R6·C3', 'R6·C4', 'R6·C5', 'R6·C6'],
                      ['R7·C0', 'R7·C1', 'R7·C2', 'R7·C3', 'R7·C4', 'R7·C5', 'R7·C6'] ];

function split2DArray_test() {
  let arrObjs = {
    oldArr: {
    obj: SourceArray,
      bounds: { row: 8, col: 7, },
      setBounds: function() {
        this.bounds.row = this.obj.length;
        this.bounds.col = this.obj[0].length;
      },
    },
    newArr: { collection: [], component: [], design: { rInit: 0, rEnd: 0, cInit: 0, cEnd: 0 } },
    splits: { atRows: [2, 3, 5], atCols: [2, 5] }
  };
  arrObjs.oldArr.setBounds();

  let i = { lv1_R: 0, lv2_C: 0 , lv3_R: 0, lv4_C: 0, slicer: 0 }; let escape = false;

  /*
    1.  Iterate through rows. (1st level)
    2.  If row excepted, continue iterating through rows. If not excepted, iterate through columns. (2nd level)
    3.  If column not excepted, RECORD ADDRESS and continue iterating through column.
    4.  When excepted column found, RECORD COLUMN - 1, and regin iterating through rows again (3rd level). When excepted row found, RECORD ROW - 1.
    5.  Record data (SliceArr): [RECORD ADDRESS[R] = RowA, RECORD ADDRESS[C] = ColA, RECORD ROW - 1 = RowB, RECORD COLUMN - 1 = ColB]
    6.  Create NewArr[] and SliceArrObj[]
    7.  Iterate through rows (r) from new SliceArr (4th level), and do SliceArrObj.push(OldArr[r].slice(ColA, ColB - ColA))
    8.  NewArr.push(SliceArrObj)
    9.  Set 2nd-level iterator to RECORD COLUMN + 1
    10. Loop should work theoretically. Untested.
  */

  Logger.log(`Excepting rows: ${arrObjs.splits.atRows.join(', ')}`);
  Logger.log(`Excepting columns: ${arrObjs.splits.atCols.join(', ')}`);

  console.time('slicer');
  for (i.lv1_R = 0; i.lv1_R < arrObjs.oldArr.bounds.row; i.lv1_R++) {
    if (arrObjs.splits.atRows.includes(i.lv1_R)) { continue; } else {
      // We've arrived at a non-excepted row.
      for (i.lv2_C = 0; i.lv2_C < arrObjs.oldArr.bounds.col; i.lv2_C++) {
        if (arrObjs.splits.atCols.includes(i.lv2_C)) { continue; } else {
          arrObjs.newArr.design.rInit = i.lv1_R; arrObjs.newArr.design.cInit = i.lv2_C;
          Logger.log(`Found origin cell '${arrObjs.oldArr.obj[i.lv1_R][i.lv2_C]}'`);
          for (i.lv3_R = arrObjs.newArr.design.rInit; i.lv3_R < arrObjs.oldArr.bounds.row; i.lv3_R++) {
            if (arrObjs.splits.atRows.includes(i.lv3_R)) {
              arrObjs.newArr.design.rEnd = i.lv3_R - 1;
              for (i.lv4_C = arrObjs.newArr.design.cInit; i.lv4_C < arrObjs.oldArr.bounds.col; i.lv4_C++) {
                if (arrObjs.splits.atCols.includes(i.lv4_C)) {
                  arrObjs.newArr.design.cEnd = i.lv4_C - 1;
                  for (i.slicer = arrObjs.newArr.design.rInit; i.slicer < arrObjs.newArr.design.rEnd + 1; i.slicer++) {
                    arrObjs.newArr.component.push([arrObjs.oldArr.obj[i.slicer].slice(arrObjs.newArr.design.cInit, arrObjs.newArr.design.cEnd + 1)]);
                  };
                  arrObjs.newArr.collection.push('Split'); // For the sake of output logging.
                  arrObjs.newArr.collection.push(arrObjs.newArr.component);
                  arrObjs.newArr.component = [];
                  i.lv2_C += 1 + arrObjs.newArr.design.cEnd - arrObjs.newArr.design.cInit;
                  arrObjs.newArr.design.rInit = 0; arrObjs.newArr.design.rEnd = 0; arrObjs.newArr.design.cInit = 0; arrObjs.newArr.design.cEnd = 0;
                  escape = true; break;
                };
              };
            };
            if (escape) { escape = false; break; };
          };
        };
      };
      i.lv2_R += 1 + arrObjs.newArr.design.rEnd - arrObjs.newArr.design.rInit;
    };
  };
  console.timeEnd('slicer');

  Logger.log(`Splitting 2D Array into:\n\n${(arrObjs.newArr.collection.join('\n\n'))}`); // The output logging.

  /* Idea Space:

    ===== PROPOSED METHOD, INCOMPLETE =====
      1. Save the origin cell of the first valid slice bounds.
      2. Iterate (FOR) through columns, starting at the Bound Minimum, and going to the Bound Maximum.
      3. If an exception row is found, save slice col bound max as (i.c - 1).
      4. Now, iterate through rows from slice origin to next exception or bound. Once this is met, save slice row bound max as (i.r - 1).
      5. Iterate through slice row bounds, pushing slices with slice column bounds as Array.slice() arguments.
      6. Push new 2D array to new array collection.

      === CONCEPTS WORTH TESTING ===

      I.    Iterative Cell Search

        Consider moving forward by setting exception or bound limits. Ex: Column iteration runs into a bound limit: slices.resume.c = false. If it's an exception, slices.resume.c = true. This way,
        any time a full 2D slice is pushed to the collection of arrays, it can take the existing current slice data and either iterate across to the next horizontal array (Resume = true), or
        iterate down to the next vertical array (Resume = false). If both Column and Row resume are false, then we are done adding sliced 2D arrays to the array collection.

        If at least one Resume is true, then another resume can be made true. Once both are true, then a new slice origin point can be made.

      II.   Iterative Bounds & Exception Search.

      1. Table Bounds defined and adjacent exceptions trimmed (Done).
          > The current exceptions are now the top-left-side borders of the desired slices.
      2. Iterate through exception indices column first (On first loop, operate from top-left bound), then row. On each, set slice start to (i.r + 1, i.c + 1), where i.? = the exception column or
         row. Set the end bounds to the index represented by the next element in the list (column or row).
  */
};
```

Comment: Please include the problem statement as text. It's currently only presented as an image, which isn't appropriate.

Comment: @cigien I don't think the attempt should have been removed. Just because no answer posted so far hasn't used the "attempt" doesn't mean  future answers would do the same.  The code also adds a explanation to the question and is valuable.

Comment: @TheMaster I really fail to see how the non-working attempt is helpful to understand the question. I've read the OP's attempt, and it adds nothing that's not already covered by the description and images of the problem. As for answers that try to fix the OP's attempt, how would that be helpful to anyone other than the OP? The goal of questions on the site is to help future readers, not the OP themselves, and the broken code in the question doesn't help future readers whatsoever.

Comment: @cigien Attempts or code in general, provide clarity, which cannot generally be expressed in plain English. It's not just code that is removed. OP postulates couple of ideas as well, which were removed. If nothing else, it provides a input array that is easily copyable. Also, the question was closed was lack of effort/being broad. I find it extremely  insulting to askers, to just remove all their effort, after reopening. (1/2)

Comment: This question has just received a close vote for "needs debugging details". It's a reasonable close vote if the question is indeed asking about how to fix the code, as it's not at all clear where, or how, the code is going wrong exactly. Since fixing the code wasn't the OP's original question, I've just removed the broken attempt, as it's fine to leave it as "how-to" question as OP originally intended.

Comment: @cigien I agree question is for future readers and not OP themselves: But do you really think anyone is going to ask this exact requirement of splitting arrays as a need? OTOH, If they were exactly interested in this exact split, it stands to reason they would be interested in OP's effort and ideas as well.(2/2)

Comment: @cigien Re: needs debugging details. The close vote was present before I even "readded the attempt"(before revision 8)

Comment: @TheMaster Ah, if it already had a CV for needing debugging details, then that CV was blatantly incorrect. I'd still rather not have the broken code in the question, to avoid future CVs for that reason. As to whether future readers will want to solve this precise requirement, I couldn't say, but if they did, I don't see what's to be gained from reading a faulty attempt. It might be nice to see where others failed, but that's more suitable to a discussion forum (or of course, a debugging question, which this wasn't until users required the OP to include their attempt.)

Comment: @cigien  The question received a  blatantly incorrect close vote, because it simply had no code.  It's typical to receive close votes for questions which have no code. Asking debugging questions is on topic and in fact most debugging questions help no one except the op. I strongly feel that the attempt edits should be restored despite being incorrect, as it adds value.

Comment: @TheMaster Yes, it's true that the question received a blatantly incorrect close vote because it had no code, and it's also true that this is typical behavior. However, I'm not aware of any guidelines that say code is mandatory, and I see no reason to add in code just to appease users who CV inappropriately. Also, debugging questions are absolutely on-topic, but this was *not* a debugging question in the first place. The OP only added in the code because users said they would reopen it if code was added. I strongly feel that the attempt adds no value, and shouldn't be in the question.

Comment: @cigien The [tour] contains _"Don't ask about...

    Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"_ It's not a close reason, but a downvote reason. To me the other part looks like the homework assignment and not like the OP's work. Without the code I would downvote. With code I wouldn't downvote. I can read a similar message when I hover the downvote button. Without the code I don't see any research effort.

Comment: @jabaa I personally vote based on whether I find a question useful, and clearly presented, not based on whether I'm convinced that the OP has worked hard to find a solution themselves. I prefer votes to be a measure of question quality, rather than a measure of the OP's effort. However, you're welcome to vote how you want. Everyone is free to vote (up/down) however they see fit, including downvoting because it's not clear whether the OP has put in enough effort into solving the problem.

Comment: @cigien OP added the attempt. It was the author's intent to add the  code based on feedback. Edits that remove it clearly conflict the author's intent. The code adds value and if anyone adds a answer that fixes the code, it will do the same thing as the existing answer. If you think existing answer would help "future readers", then the debugged answer will also help future readers. I really don't see any reason to remove the code. Furthermore, questions shouldn't be edited to encourage "gimme the codez" type of questions, which are already a plague.

Comment: @TheMaster I don't really have anything to add to what I've covered above. I'm also not going to get into a rollback war (one rollback is the limit I try to stick to). If you feel the question is improved by the code attempt, that's fine. Unfortunately, as the question stands now, it *does* need debugging details, so I just hope it doesn't end up getting closed for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

In the approach I take below, I split up the problem in two main steps:

```
const ranges = (splits, length) => [...splits, length].reduce(
  (r, e, i, a) => (s = i ? a[i - 1] + 1 : 0, e - s ? [...r, {s, e}] : r),
  []
);

const blocks = (array, rowRanges, colRanges) => rowRanges.map(
  ({s, e}) => array.slice(s, e)
).map(block => colRanges.map(
  ({s, e}) => block.map(row => row.slice(s,e))
)).flat();
```

- The **`ranges()`** function takes an input array containing "splits" information (i.e. `rowSplits` or `colSplits`), and then uses that information to create an array of ranges for the row blocks or column blocks. Each range is defined as an object of type `{s: number, e: number}`, where `s` is the start of the range (inclusive) and `e` is the end (exclusive). The [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) operation used in this function makes it so that empty ranges are filtered out.
- The **`blocks()`** function takes the 2D array and the row and column ranges as input. It first uses the row ranges to split the 2D array into row blocks, and then uses the column ranges to split those blocks down to the regions defined in the problem statement. The splitting operations are all implemented by [mapping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the ranges to their corresponding array [slices](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice). Finally, the entire result is [flattened](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to arrive at the required output.

---

**Complete snippet:**

```js
const rows = 8;
const cols = 7;
const arrOld = Array.from(
  { length: rows}, (_, y) => Array.from(
    { length: cols }, (_, x) => `${y}, ${x}`
  )
);
const rowSplits = [2, 3, 5];
const colSplits = [2, 6];

const ranges = (splits, length) => [...splits, length].reduce(
  (r, e, i, a) => (s = i ? a[i - 1] + 1 : 0, e - s ? [...r, {s, e}] : r),
  []
);

const blocks = (array, rowRanges, colRanges) => rowRanges.map(
  ({s, e}) => array.slice(s, e)
).map(block => colRanges.map(
  ({s, e}) => block.map(row => row.slice(s,e))
)).flat();

const arrNew = blocks(
  arrOld,
  ranges(rowSplits, rows),
  ranges(colSplits, cols)
);

console.log(arrNew);
```

Comment: Thanks! Before I incorporate this, I'm going to try and understand what it's doing first. Just being honest with you, this is not something that I understand very well at all. Any suggested resources for understanding the Array.map() and arrow functions? For what these functions appear to be able to do, it looks like these have been a weak spot in my skills for an inexcusably long time.